# Multiple Combobox with same Itemsource but the SelectedItem should be different - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, observablecollection

**Goal** is to have multiple `Combobox`, once the item is selected in any of the `Combobox`, it should be removed or hided from other `Combobox`es for selection.

I'm able to change the source whenever the selection got changed on any of the `Combobox`es. But **Problem** is when I remove the selected item from the `ItemsSource`, item got removed from all the sources including the one on which I selected.

Here is the sample

**xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="50" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems}" />
    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="50" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems}" />
    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="50" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems}" />
    <ComboBox Width="100" Height="50" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems}" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Codebehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<string> s = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        s.Add("item1");
        s.Add("item2");
        s.Add("item3");
        s.Add("item4");
        s.Add("item5");
        s.Add("item6");

        DataContext = new MainViewModel() { ComboboxItems = s , SelectedItem = "item2" };

    }
}

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> comboboxitems;

    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboboxItems
    {
        get { return comboboxitems; }  
        set { comboboxitems = value; OnPropertyChanged("ComboboxItem"); }
    }

    private string _selectedItem;

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            comboboxitems.Remove(value);  //here removing selected item from itemssource
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

I know I can have multiple Collection for each `Combobox` but that may take lot of memory if number of `Combobox` increases.

Hope, there should be a easy way to achieve this in WPF.

Comment: Well in this case you would have to create multiple SelectedItem properties, one for each combobox I believe. eg SelectedItem1, SelectedItem2 and so on, but the ItemsSource can be shared.

Comment: Use CollectionView or CollectionViewSource- which is proxy for your actual source. This will allow to share common source via View property and you can have different selected items(CurrentItem) for each CollectionView.

Comment: @adminSoftDK Yes we can., but how can I remove or restrict the item from selection on other `Combobox`?

Comment: Each combobox would need a style and triggers, to do this. So if the current item equals OtherSelectedItem then apply something to this item. I don't have the time to make a code sample right now. But hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define different `SelectedItem` for each `ComboBox`, and then create a wrapper of the `SharedItemSource` for each `ComboBox`to filter out the `SelectedItem` of other `ComboBox`. eg:

C# :

```
    public IEnumerable<string> ComboboxItems1
    {
        get
        {
            return ComboboxItems.Where(x => x != SelectedItem2 && x != SelectedItem3);
        }
    }

    public string SelectedItem1
    {
        get { return _selectedItem1; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem1 != value)
            {
                _selectedItem1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem1");
                RaisePropertyChanged("ComboboxItems2"); //raise propertychanged to refresh GUI 
                RaisePropertyChanged("ComboboxItems3");
            }
        }
    }       

    public IEnumerable<string> ComboboxItems2
    {
        get
        {
            return ComboboxItems.Where(x => x!=SelectedItem1&&x!=SelectedItem3);
        }
    }

    public string SelectedItem2
    {
        get { return _selectedItem2; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem2 != value)
            {
                _selectedItem2 = value;                   
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem2");
                RaisePropertyChanged("ComboboxItems1"); //raise propertychanged to refresh GUI
                RaisePropertyChanged("ComboboxItems3");
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ComboboxItems3
    {
        get
        {
            return ComboboxItems.Where(x => x != SelectedItem1 && x != SelectedItem2);
        }
    }

    public string SelectedItem3
    {
        get { return _selectedItem3; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem3 != value)
            {
                _selectedItem3 = value;                 
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem3");
                RaisePropertyChanged("ComboboxItems1"); //raise propertychanged to refresh GUI
                RaisePropertyChanged("ComboboxItems2");
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem1}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems1}" />
<ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems2}" />
<ComboBox  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem3}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboboxItems3}" />
```

Comment: . I leads to `Stack overflow` exception as the `ItemsSource` refresh the `SelectedItem1`.

Comment: Can you set up a break point and try to get more information about the exception.

Comment: Yes.  On `OnPropertyChanged("ComboboxItems1");` it again triggers the `Set` of `SelectedItem1` which leads to deadlock.

Comment: Could you post relevant code, it's not possible from the code I posted above.

Comment: I think in your code, we are have a `ItemsSource` in a `Combobox`, on setting the `SelectedItem` in GUI triggers the `Set` of `SelectedItem` property on VM.  Now, in `Set` we again changing the `ItemsSource` of the same `Combobox` where the previously `SelectedItem` is not there now as it is added to `C#Remove`.  So it again triggers the `Set` of `SelectedItem` property and the loop goes on. .

Comment: @Gopichandar, now I understand. So when you are removing the `selectedItem`, the `comboBox` still has to show an item as selected, which has caused the lock.  Please see my updated answer, which added condition ` if(_selectedItem1 != value)` and will only trigger `propertychange` when selection has been changed.

Comment: This is not going to give us solution as the selected item should be removed from other Comboboxes but not on the selected one. Also, if I change the selected item from a previously selected one, the previous one should be added for selection on others. Isn't it. . Hope I am clear

Comment: I misunderstand your requirement a little bit, but it's easy to be fixed. I will update shortly.

Comment: Updated one is _Perfect!_  Really thanks for you effort on this.

Comment: @Gopichandar, glad it helped.